# Setting up SSL certificate in Visual Studio development project

Tags: ssl

I'm very new to Visual Studio and Microsoft platform development in general.  I have inherited a C#/React web application in mid-development from a programmer who just left the company.  The server side of the application is C# code set up in a Visual Studio 2017 project and running on .NET Core 2.1.  The application runs, but my development and debugging is slowed substantially by the fact that I'm constantly having to go through Privacy Error pages.  How do I go about setting up an SSL certificate so the HTTPS will work properly?

I installed dotnet-dev-certs, ran the "dotnet dev-certs https" command, and got the "A valid HTTPS certificate is already present" response.  What are my next steps, to get it attached properly to the VS project and/or React application?
I went into IIS Manager to see if that's where I need to do it, but there's no entry there for the VS project, just for "Default Web Site".